# .net RDF DBLP querying

Tags: rdf

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String st = "";
        String qry = "";
        String uri_V;
        String dguri_V;

        // uri_V = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
        // dguri_V = "http://dbpedia.org";

        uri_V = "http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/sparql";

        // Modify if need......
        //String ns = "\""+TextBox1.Text.ToString()+"\"";
        // String qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ?name WHERE { ?person foaf:name ?name.FILTER regex(str(?name),"+ns+").}";

        qry = "SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x dcterms:issued ?year} LIMIT 20";
        //  qry = "SELECT ?name WHERE { ?x dcterms:issued ?year. FILTER (?year>2011). ?x dc:creator ?author. ?author foaf:name ?name. } LIMIT 20";
        /* if (radiosrch.SelectedIndex == 0)
         {
             qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 5";
         }
         else// if (radiosrch.SelectedIndex == 1) 
         {
             // qry= "query for publisher."
             qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ?Concept WHERE {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 5";
         }
         */

        //Common
        SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri(uri_V));//, dguri_V);
        SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(qry);
        foreach (SparqlResult result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            st = st + result.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        TextBox3.Text = st.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}

}
```

I get the following error :
`VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException: A HTTP Error occurred while trying to make the SPARQL Query, see inner exception for details ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.ExecuteQuery(Uri target, String postData, String accept) at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryInternal(String sparqlQuery, String acceptHeader) at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(ISparqlResultsHandler handler, String sparqlQuery) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(ISparqlResultsHandler handler, String sparqlQuery) at VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(String sparqlQuery) at Index.ImageButton1_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in d:\SPARQL\Index.aspx.cs:line 53`

But when i run this query on http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/snorql endpoint,I GET ABSOLUTELY NO ERRORS.
PLZ HELP ME OUT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you have failed to define any `PREFIX` declarations in your SPARQL query yet you have used prefixed name abbreviations for URIs in your query.

Therefore the remote server is quite within its rights to return a `400 Bad Request` because it does not know what you are asking.

If you weren't aware of it already try using the online [SPARQL Query Validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) which can provide a useful sanity check of your queries.  Your query as written gives the following error when inputted there:

> Line 1, column 22: Unresolved prefixed name: dcterms:issued

Your query should be the following to be valid:

```
String qry = @"PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x dcterms:issued ?year} LIMIT 20";
```

You may also want to look at the [Querying with SPARQL](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Querying%20with%20SPARQL) documentation which in the Representing Queries section includes an example of using the [SparqlParameterizedString](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/index.asp?Topic=VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlParameterizedString) class instead to build a query with pre-defined prefixes e.g.

```
SparqlParameterizedString queryString = new SparqlParameterizedString();
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("dcterms", new Uri("http://purl.org/dc/terms/"));
queryString.CommandText = "SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x dcterms:issued ?year} LIMIT 20";
```

Then you just need to call `ToString()` on `queryString` when you are ready to pass it to your remote endpoint.

Comment: Thanx a ton sir,u r a saviour,my project is finally running!!
:)